# Proving non-existance of a Hamiltonian circuit when separated into multiple components

Tags: graph-theory

The Theorem I have to prove is the following

Prove that if there exists a non-empty proper subset S of graph G such that G-S has more components than |S|, then G is non-Hamiltonian

I'm not sure where to start.

**Attempt**

A graph is Hamiltonian if it contains a Hamiltonian cycle. i.e. If there exists a path in G (for |G| = n) of the form:
1-2-3-4-......-n-1

where 1,2,3,... are the vertices of the graph

I'm thinking of maybe doing a proof by contradiction:

Assume that there is a Hamiltonian graph such that when it is separated by S, there are more than |S| components.

I don't know where to go from here.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank You

Comment: You must distinguish whether, in your case, Hamiltonian mean containing a Hamiltonian *path* or *cycle*.  I think you mean a path.  Have you first come up with an intuition about why the statement is true?  This is the 1st step, then comes the writing.  Try drawing a set $S$, with more components, and look at what a Hamiltonian path must do.  It has to enter each component through a vertex of $S$, then exit through a different vertex of $S$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I meant to say cycle.

Comment: I've tried for more than two hours, but I can't seem to think about this intuitively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hamiltonian graph and connected components](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501913/hamiltonian-graph-and-connected-components)

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_1, ..., C_k$ be components of $G-S$, and suppose that $k \gt |S|$. If G is not a connected graph, there is no Hamiltonian cycles. So suppose that G is connected. Hence, every component of $G-S$ must have a neighbor in S.
For sake of contradiction, suppose that $C^*$ is a Hamiltonian cycle of $G$. Give an arbitrary orientation to edges of $C^*$ Let $x_i$ be the last vertex of $S$, visited in $C^*$, before visiting a vertex of $C_i$ $(1 \leq i \leq k)$. $x_1, x_2, ..., x_k$ are distinct vertices in $S$. A countradiction with $k \gt |S|$.